# How to deal with non-normally distributed data?

Tags: r, distributions, proportion, count-data

I have a proportion data (0-100%, or it can be count data 0-20) that is not normally distributed. The hist graph in R shows:[image: hist graph of raw data]
I have tried many ways to transfer data (log, coxbox, ranktransfer), but non of them works.
Is there any other way that I can transfer these data to normal distribution?
If not, I think the only way is to use non-parametric test or generalized linear model to analyze my data, am I right?
Then the question is: if I want to use glm in R, which distribution family I should choose?

Comment: Count data and proportion data are, by definition, not normal. If you search for "glm count data" or "glm proportion data" there are many guides and resources.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you say it can be count data, what do you mean? 

What statistical test are you trying to conduct?

Comment: The post doesn't mention a test, it talks about a model - models have more uses than just testing.

Comment: Seems like binomial glm to me

Comment: What do you need a normal distribution for? What exactly is your aim? You only show one variable, a glm needs at least two, so we don't know enough to answer.